# How to upload a image using Ajax in django

Tags: ajax, django, django-forms, django-ajax-selects

Background :
I have a simple model form with a image field.

```
class XYZForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = XYZ
        fields = ( 'file',)
```

The model is

```
class XYZ(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField(null = True)
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_photo_storage_path, null = True)
```

Problem:
I am submitting this form via ajax. But this form is not validating, as the file is not being stored.Is there a particular way of submitting forms with files via ajax ?

P.S. :- request.FILES is empty in the view, where the form is being submitted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to use django-swfupload:

http://swfupload.googlecode.com

Comment: Do we need to add a plugin even for a single image upload ?

Comment: I just thought looking/using some solution would help you recognize your problem. Because you didn't show almost any code to see where can problem be. Ie - don't you miss enctype="multipart/form-data" parametr in form element? How does your ajax call looks like? etc.

Answer (score 2):

Files can't be send using ajax, you can mimic an ajax upload by using a iframe for uploading.

Nice example: http://embrangler.com/2010/08/ajax-uploads-images-in-django/

Answer (score 1):

I used this one https://github.com/GoodCloud/django-ajax-uploader
But I used without 
It is pretty easy to use,